# Passing object to Django custom filter

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I am using Django 3.2

I am writing a moderation app, and I want to be able to display only approved values in my template.

I want to be able to use the new filter like this:

```
{{ moderated_object.field_name | approved }}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter(name='approved')
def moderator_approved_field_value(moderated_object, fieldname):

    return moderated_object.approved_value(fieldname)
```

As I have written the filter above, I can only use it like this:

```
{{ moderated_object| approved: fieldname }}
```

Which is ugly. Is there a way that I can pass the object to the function behind the scenes, so that I can use the cleaner way of using the filter in my template?

Answer (score 0):

im my opinion django allow a bad deсigion with template filters.
You have a template and render function. You have a context.
You can send in context already the result of moderated_object.approved_value(fieldname).

```
def get_context(...):
    ...
    context[moderated_object] = moderated_object.approved_value(fieldname)
    ...
```

template

```
{{ moderated_object }}
```

two `}}`, not three `}}}`

you can tell me: i create a loop with some additional elements in template.

answer - additional logic in template is bad, but, if you want - you can create a generator before:

```
def get_context(...):
    ...
    context[moderated_objects] = ((obj, obj.approved_value(fieldname)) for obj in context[moderated_objects])
    ...
```

template

```
{% for obj, approvement in moderated_objects %}
   {{ approvement }} 
   {{ moderated_object }}
{% endfor %}
```

all is possible. Try to think completely without template filter. And you find the best way, i am shure.